# What's the right way to sort the child object by their property in a Map in Immutable.js

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

I have an Map `m`:

```
var m = Immutable.fromJS({
    first: {a: 6, b: 3},
    second: {a: 3, b: 6},
    third: {a: 2, b: 4}
})
```

I want to get the child objects in `m` sorted by their property `b`, like this:

```
[
    {a: 6, b: 3},
    {a: 2, b: 4},
    {a: 3, b: 6}
]
```

I have tried below:

```
m.valueSeq().sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.get('b') > b.get('b')
}).toJS()
```

It works well in Chrome and node.js, but in Safari v8.0 in OS X, the result is

```
[
    {a: 6, b: 3},
    {a: 3, b: 6},
    {a: 2, b: 4}
]
```

It did not sort at all! This made some bugs in my React/Redux app. What's the matter of it? And what is the right way to sort it? Thanks!

Comment: You're returning a boolean when you ought to be returning a number. `return a.get('b') - b.get('b')`. When `a` is greater, this returns a positive number. When `b` is greater, it returns a negative, and when equal, it returns `0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your custom compare function requires the returning of 1, -1 or 0 in order to sort the items correctly.

```
m.valueSeq().sort(function(a, b) {
  if (a.get('b') > b.get('b')) return 1;
  if (a.get('b') < b.get('b')) return -1;
  else return 0;
}).toJS();
```